Relation between condition number and relative error
For the equation $Ax=b, A \in \mathbb{R}^{m*n}, x \in \mathbb{R}^n, b \in \mathbb{R}^m$, the condition number of $A$ gives an upper bound of the relative error in $x$ given a relative error in $b$:
$||\frac{\delta x}{x}|| \leq \kappa(A) ||\frac{\delta b}{b}|| $
Now I multiply $\Lambda \Lambda^{-1}$ in between $Ax$, where $\Lambda=diag(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, ..., \lambda_n)$. The equation becomes $A\Lambda \Lambda^{-1}x=b$ and let $A'=A\Lambda, x'=\Lambda^{-1}x$. The equation becomes $A'x'=b$. There will be a new upper bound for the new matrix and new coordinate:
$||\frac{\delta x'}{x'}|| \leq \kappa(A') ||\frac{\delta b}{b}|| $
How do I relate $||\frac{\delta x}{x}||$ to $||\frac{\delta x'}{x'}||$? I assume this change of coordinate will not change the upper bound of the relative error of the original coordinate. Even if in the new coordinate system, $A'$ may have a better condition number, when the error of $x'$ is mapped back to $x$, the error in $x$ remains the same. I don't know if that's true or how to prove it.
Thank you!

The condition number for the Euclidean norm is given in closed form as $\kappa(A) = |A||A^{-1}|$.

Hi Kakashi Sang, I understand that and it becomes $\frac{\sigma_{max}}{\sigma_{min}}$. How would that help my question? Thank you!
